# No USB devices or running emulators detected, despite ADB detecting the phone successfully

Tags: android, linux, debian, adb

I know this question was asked a lot, but going through dozens of answers none have been helpful. 
I'm attempting to run a simple hello world on my Huawei Mate 9 using Android Studio 2.3.1 (The APP is 4.X Jellybean API) running on Debian (Jesse).

-I have enabled debugging options on the phone (I can see developer options)

-Installed the SDK and ADB through the Android Studio.

-Device is being detected successfully on ADB devices.*

-I have tried MTP and PTP (currently it's on PTP)

Despite all different combinations I don't see my phone ready for uploading my program.

*With android studio closed:
when I check adb it usually never finds the phone the first time (adb devices) but after i do kill-server and start-server, i get the unique phone ID the second time I run adb devices. Needless to say, should I run studio after the second time around when it detects it, the phone still does not appear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after rigorous search, I've found the reason for incapability of finding the phone in the android select deployment target menu is due to an option within a hash code menu.

You need to dial *#*#2846579#*#* (works on Huawei 7 and onwards phones) in order to find a hidden window, for me it says ProjectMenu as the activity title name, then you must pick Background Settings->Background Debug->Open then restart your phone, should you have avd,android running well on your pc and debugging options activated on your phone this is all that's needed in order to deploy your app successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this two solutions :

1) Go to setting and than in security and enable " Unknown source " to allow installation of apps from unknown source. If its still not working try second solution.

2) This problem can be due to unsupported adb driver of you mobile model. For this Download [PdaNet+](http://pdanet.co/a/) a universal adb driver downloader for all devices. It will ask to remove current driver and go for it. It will fix all the adb driver related issue.

Link : http://pdanet.co/a/

Comment: I went File->Settings and then checked all tabs and couldn't find security.. unless I'm missing something? would like to try the first solution first, as you've mentioned..

Comment: Also, pdanet+ is not available for linux

Comment: you don't need adb driver for linux , and unknown source option may be in other section of your device setting find it ... also perform wire less debugging because may be wire fault.  Link : [link](http://codetheory.in/android-debug-bridge-adb-wireless-debugging-over-wi-fi/)